# Projective over an affine is quasiprojective

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Given a projective resolution of singularities $\pi: Y \rightarrow X$ over an affine variety $X,$ how can we prove that a smooth scheme Y is a quasi projective variety?

Comment: $Y\hookrightarrow X\times\mathbb{P}^n\hookrightarrow \mathbb{A}^m\times\mathbb{P}^n\hookrightarrow\mathbb{P}^m\times\mathbb{P}^n\hookrightarrow\mathbb{P}^{(m+1)(n+1)-1}$, where the last one is by Segre embedding.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like I should have put this one in Mathstack, sorry about that. The first embedding is from the definition of $\pi$ being projective I guess?

Comment: Yep (The Hartshorne-style definition of projective morphism, at least)

Comment: Thanks! Though, in Hartshorne it says that $\pi$ being projective rather means that there is a closed immersion $Y \rightarrow X \times \mathbb{P}^n$, so not necessarily an embedding?

Comment: No, it's meant to be an embedding, i.e. locally on rings given by $A\to A/I$. (I'm not sure if H. defines "immersion" as distinct from "embedding" anywhere, but in that spot it's meant to be an embedding)

Comment: Allright, thanks!